# Execution of a program

Tags: java, c++, vba

I have a question about execution of program. In C++ for example, the program is being executed line by line until it reaches the end (return 0; or just reaches the end of the scope of the main function). In a program with a text interface if I want to repeat the program until a user for instance hits the [Esc] key I put it in the loop that is being executed until that specific one situation occurs. Same happens in a GUI program (precisely: WinAPI), program is looping through the event loop until for example user hits 'X' and then the program is reaching the end of the main function, so the execution of the program stops. So far so good.

What is surprising me and is keeping me up at night is the fact that when I create a JFrame object, initialize it and make it happen just to show it, when the program execution reaches the end of the scope of the main function, the window still exists. I've also checked it in a debugger that it's not showing a line that is actually being executed. It clearly states that the thread execution has been finished. I am sure that the execution is not being frozen so something has to be happening under the hood, cause I still can resize, close the window and so on. So here's my question: where is actually the execution of a program 'moving to' when a window in Java is being displayed?

Same thing is happening in VBA. I've created a main function in a module, then in that one module i've forced one non-modal form to show and once the execution of the function has finished, the window did not disappear, but the variables declared in the function did, so the access to them vanished as well.

In both examples in C/C++ those situations would mean, that program was finished, but there's that window visible, so the application actually didn't stop, right?

Comment: *In C++ for example, the program is being executed line by line until it reaches the end* **what**? this is true for any language. There are multiple threads in every serious application. In Java, at a minimum, there is a *garbage collector* and if you're using Swing then there is an Event Dispatch Thread.

Comment: In the Java example the GUI is handled by a separate thread. In VBA the execution context is the application that the code is used in.